# Woocommerce REST API 404 error

Tags: wordpress, curl, woocommerce

Since woocommerce released the 2.1 version with REST API feature, I tried to use it: I activated the API on my woocommerce admin panel but when I try to call the curl: http://www.mydomain.com/wc-api/v1/

the response is a 404 file not found error.

I tried to check everything in internet, I've read woocommerce docs but I cannot figure out what I have to do: probably some setting in the server apache or php... I don't know..

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Show your code.

Comment: In the case of wordpress it is not possible. Or which code do you mean?

Comment: I have the same issue with my wordpress. It makes no difference, if I host the wordpress or i pay for a free version on there servers... Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 34):

Try going, on the Admin Panel, to Settings -> Permalinks. On Default Settings radio group, select the "Post name" one. Save the changes.

Worked for me; hope for you too. :)

Source: [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20140523212829/http://www.jmawebtechnologies.com/support/ccc/woocommerce-quickbooks-installation).

EDIT: Website is not available, so I put its Wayback Machine URL.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this same issue.  I had forgotten to turn on the pretty perma links, but doing that didn't solve it for me.

I also had to update my apache virtual host file because the AllowOverride was defaulted to None.

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once I updated this, and reloaded the Apache service, the API worked for me.

Comment: Is this also possible for a Node.js server?

Comment: @Yvonne.J.M I don't know that I understand the question.  The apache server that needed this applied to it was the server running the wordpress website, not the server I was trying to make the API calls from.   I'm not entirely sure where the Node.js server would fit into this.

Answer (score 4):

It was simply a matter of enabling URL rewriting in WordPress. Basically, go to `Settings -> Permalinks` and make sure the first rewriting option is set to `Posts Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from answer shared above: Settings -> Permalinks. On Default Settings radio group, select the "Post name" one. Save the changes.

I also had to manually update `.htaccess` file to reflect the changes I made (permalinks to "Post name", and the little Wordpress help text shown on the bottom of the page was really helpful:

> If your .htaccess file was writable, we could do this automatically,
> but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in
> your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select
> all.

Basically copy the new mod_rewrite rules as instructed by Wordpress above and manually update your .htaccess file! doing this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I use MAMP to run the Wordpress and utilizing the web server Nginx. When I tried running REST API, it returns 404 status not found. I set permalinks to 'Post Name' but it still didn't work.

Then I changed the web server to **Apache**. It works.