# WooCommerce REST API error: Invalid URL, no WC API found

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

I'm trying to start out with the [WooCommerce REST API client library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) but keep getting this error:

> Invalid URL, no WC API found at http://[my-store].com/wc-api/v2/ --
>   ensure your store URL is correct and pretty permalinks are enabled.

Pretty permalinks are enabled and set to post name, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710078/woocommerce-rest-api-404-error). Manually accessing the URL via browser gives the JSON output of some WooCommerce settings, that's why I assume that the store URL is correct. (It's same like the domain, I'm working on.) I also tried to insert new consumer and secret keys but that doesn't help.

A bit of research in the code brought me to the class-wc-api-client.php.

```
$index = @file_get_contents( $this->api_url );

// check for HTTP 404 response (file_get_contents() returns false when encountering 404)
// this usually means:
// 1) the store URL is not correct (missing sub-directory path, etc)
// 2) pretty permalinks are disabled
if ( false === $index ) {
    throw new WC_API_Client_Exception( sprintf( 'Invalid URL, no WC API found at %s -- ensure your store URL is correct and pretty permalinks are enabled.', $this->api_url ), 404 );
```

**$index** indeed equals false, which means that file_get_contents got a 404 response. Creating  a */wc-api/v2/* directory within the store's directory didn't help.

I can't find out why file_get_contents gets a 404 response while browsing the page will display a non-empty JSON string. I feel like I'm missing something basic.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Edit:** Found the solution! I encountered this problem again today and did some research on the file_get_contents() returning FALSE on JSON. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688966/php-json-returning-boolfalse) put me on the right track. Setting *allow_url_fopen = On* in the PHP.ini solves the case. Might be useful to know if someone else runs into this problem.

Comment: This will sound strange but suddenly it works. I don't know why -- I reverted every change I made for solving this problem. So the system status is exactly the same like when I made the original post. I talked to my hoster and they, too, said they didn't make any changes. I guess this question is resolved. I'll do an edit, when I finally find out something useful about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My problem was caused by one of the settings in iTheme Security. Under banned users -> Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature. If you have the list enabled, then itheme keeps a ist of the allowed user agents in the .htaccess. When you are using php's file_get_contents, there is no user agent, so the script ends up being blocked.

If anyone else is having problems with this, I suggest looking through your .htaccess to see if there is anything suspicious.